# Django chartit causes Mysql date json serialization error

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a problem with plotting a graph using django chartit.
I'd like to draw a plot with price on y axis and date on x axis

The error is

```
TypeError at /plots/archiveRange/2010-09-09/2012-09-11

datetime.date(2015, 1, 2) is not JSON serializable
```

The problem comes from using mysql database with chartit library (which apparently cannot retrieve  date in sql format). This is my view:

```
myData = DailyStateArchive.objects.filter(company_name = '06MAGNA')

ds = DataPool(
  series=
    [{'options': {
        'source': myData },
      'terms': [
          'date',
          'price'
        ]},

    ])

chart = Chart(
        datasource = ds, 
        series_options = 
          [{'options':{
              'type': 'line',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
              'date' : [
                'price'
                ]
              }}],
        chart_options = 
          {'title': {
               'text': 'My Plot'},
           'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Date'}}})
```

Model looks like this:

```
class DailyStateArchive(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('data')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    company_isin = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 8, decimal_places = 2)
    volume = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem in stupid way but some say that if it seems stupid but it works it is not stupid.

The solution was to modify simplejson library, more specifically it was 'simplejson/encoder.py' file. I've changed the 'default' method which is normally supposed to be overriden by more complex types from:

```
def default(self, o):
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

to:

```
def default(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, date):
        return o.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

I also had to add 'from datetime import date' on the top.
I was trying to do it otherwise but only this solution worked. I hope it will help someone in the future, and I also hope someone suggests better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You got a `Not JSON Serializable Object` in this case a `date` comming from the field `date` in `DailyStateArchive`, you will need pre-process that value to send it to the view. You could try this:

```
myData = DailyStateArchive.objects.filter(company_name='06MAGNA').values()

for data in myData:
    data['date'] = data['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ds = DataPool(
  series=
    [{'options': {
        'source': myData },
      'terms': [
          'date',
          'price'
        ]},

    ])

chart = Chart(
        datasource = ds, 
        series_options = 
          [{'options':{
              'type': 'line',
              'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
              'date' : [
                'price'
                ]
              }}],
        chart_options = 
          {'title': {
               'text': 'My Plot'},
           'xAxis': {
                'title': {
                   'text': 'Date'}}})
```

Comment: I've tried your solution using 'python manage.py shell' and the result was fine, but the web browser still shows the same error. I'm not sure but it may have something to do with cache.